# How to run a function before closing the shell after pressing OK on the Kill prompt in Python 3.7.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script running in the shell (3.7.4). While it's still running, if I want to close it, a kill prompt pops ups asking me "Your program is still running Do you want to kill it?". If I click OK, it stops executing. But I want to execute a function after pressing OK and before Killing the program. How to implement this?

I'm new to Python. Started using it from last week. So no idea where to begin.

If I click OK on the kill prompt I want to run something like this:
myobj.Uninitialize()

and then close the execution

Comment: You may be looking for the [`atexit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html#module-atexit).

Comment: atexit works in normal exit. I tried atexit. But didn't do the trick. In my case I'm interested in hard exit

Comment: the way I solved it was: created a GUI and created a "close"  button and tied some functions (gracefully exiting and so on) to it. That was my solution. Worked out for me. But still would like to tie those functionalities to the "close" button of python shell.